# How could we synthesize tert-butyl-alcohol, starting with just methane as only carbon source?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

would it be possible to synthesize tert-butyl-alcohol with methane as the only carbon source? I mean, I almost figured it out, so basically methane is radically substituted by bromine under UV, then it is given to a suspension of Li in dimethyl ether, and in the last step, it is combined with CO2 (dry ice or by burning CH4) to yield the lithium propane-2,2-bis(olate), but I don't get the last step where we would get the tert-butyl-alcohol.

[image]

How would only adding water give the tert-butyl alcohol?

Comment: Carbon dioxide is also a carbon source in this scheme. Presumably the last step is to add more MeLi to the acetone, and something got skipped in the scheme.

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, the addition of MeLi to lithium carboxylate to form the dilithioalkoxide, requires carboxylic acid salts of 6 carbons or greater. There is solubility problem. As an academic exercise, this example is fine. Follow @orthocresol’s lead. If you have access to Organic Reactions, you can read Margaret Jorgenson’s review here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/0471264180.or018.01